# Passing more than one parameter in making call from factory in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following factory

```
App.factory("myRepository", ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
        myRecord: $resource('api/inst/Getinst/:id,name', { last: '@id', name: '@name' }, { query: { method: 'GET' } })
    };
}]);
```

I am trying to pass two parameters named id and name url. This is not working. 
Please let me know how to pass more than one parameters with the url. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$resource('api/inst/Getinst/:id/:name', { last: '@id', name: '@name' }, { query: { method: 'GET' } })
```

There is a example on [angular resource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) that should help